# how to install e17 on ubuntu server

Tags: desktop-environments

I'd like to install e 17 on ubuntu server and have added the ppa and installed lightdm allready.  But when I try to choose e17 at the login there is no option to choose it. When i log in the screen gets black and a second later ldm is on screen again.

Mey any one help me, please.

Thanks a lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Ubuntu server installed with LXDE.  To install E17 Desktop, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install e17
```

To start e17, all I had to do is log out of the LXDE session, and choose the Enlightenment session.  See images below.

[image]

[image]